# How to handle Python KeyError while implementing automata?

Tags: python

I am implementing a simple automata function using Python.

```
def RunAutomata(transition, initial, accepting, s):
    state = initial
    for c in s:
        try:
            state = transition[state][c]
        except KeyError:
            return False
    return state in accepting

dfa = {0:{'a':1, 'b':2},
       1:{'c':3,'d':2},
       2:{'f':3},
       3:{'e':1}}

RunAutomata(dfa, 0, {2}, 'bfecedfedf')
```

**Intuition for this piece of code:** It checks the dfa and string to find out whether that string is accepted under the given dfa. If accepted return True else return False.

Here you can see, in the dictionary, I have used alphabetic keys, So while traversing, if key not found, it throws KeyError. 
I handle it using try-except block, but I want to know if any better alternative available for this to work with out using exception handling funda.

**Edit:** Got a solution from @omri_sadon. Thank you. Please feel free to post some other different ways as well.

Comment: Note that this `try`-`except` way is not intrisically bad.

Comment: True that, But I want to know other possible way to do the same, As I am new to python,

Comment: @Jyotirmay You have no terminal states...?

Comment: I don't understand, What is terminal states?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the dict `get` method .

```
transition.get(state) # default for None

transition.get(state, False) # If key not in dict, False is returned
```

The method `get()` returns the value within a given key.

If key is not in the dict, the default value is returned.

Comment: Since this is not so trivial, could you please explain why it is acceptable to return a `None` value?

Comment: Thank you.. Here I modified the code to get What I wanted. {
def RunAutomata(transition, initial, accepting, s):
    state = initial
    for c in s:
        state = transition[state].get(c)
    return state in accepting

dfa = {0:{'a':1, 'b':2},
       1:{'c':3,'d':2},
       2:{'f':3},
       3:{'e':1}}

RunAutomata(dfa, 0, {2}, 'bfecedfedfed')}

Comment: @Rightleg , What do you mean? That way you won't get an exception and you can handle it the way you want whenever the `get` method return None. You can return other values except None, it depends on the business flow.

Comment: I think we cannot put a keyword argument like default=None..  With that the code is breaking, otherwise, it is working fine. Anyway.. Thanks.

Comment: @Jyotirmay `transition.get(state, False)` You can try this.